# Angular 2 - I can't output my values from JSON (TypeScript)

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm trying to output a list using *ngFor in Angular 2, but the only way to actualy get something on the screen  is to do something like:

```
<li *ngFor="let node of nodes">{{node | json}}</li>
```

which of course, will return all the JSON

if I do something like this

```
<li *ngFor="let node of nodes">{{node.title}}</li>
```

I will get printed [object Object]

This is how my app.component.ts looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  getData: string;
  postData: string;
  nodes = [{title : "basic page 1", content: "test page in Drupal 8 ..."}, {title : "basic page 2", content: "Another page in Drupal 8 ..."}];

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get("http://the-server.co.uk/rest/export/json/basic").
        toPromise().then(r => r.json()).then(r => this.nodes = r);
        }
}
```

This is how my Objects are looking in console:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not want to JSON.parse(r) in Promise callback?

Comment: I think  I've tried that but I guess my experience is not good enough to make it work properly.

Comment: What's the result if you print out {{node | json}}?

Comment: I get a list of my articles...but is raw JSON...just to give you a short example, {{node.title | json}} give me this: [ { "value": "The second test page" } ] [ { "value": "Test Page 1" } ]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your response object has the "title" of the type array (`array[1]`), that's the reason you are seeing `[object Object]` printed. You can try expanding the `title` and put that in the template.

```
{{node.title."titiledummy"}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/a9k3wDbaKFIfYqWgf78x?p=preview

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<li *ngFor="let node of nodes">{{node.title[0].key}}</li>`
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  private nodes = [{title : "basic page 1", content: "test page in Drupal 8 ..."}, {title : "basic page 2", content: "Another page in Drupal 8 ..."}];

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
this.nodes = [{title : [{'key':"basic page 1"}], content: "test page in Drupal 8 ..."}, {title : [{'key':"basic page 2"}], content: "Another page in Drupal 8 ..."}];

}
```

Comment: Under title, I have another object and under that I have the value I want...see the updated image

Comment: just posted the link to the plunker with the working example